# I cannot consume big message on DurableSubscriber

Tags: java, jms, apache-axis, soa, jms-topic

My Java program is running on a VMWare-Windows-Server, it connects to a SOA bus and get messages from `DurableSubscriber`. It is running since 2 years without problem.

Since last week, it could not receive any messages. In debug-mode (together with server side), we found the problem. If a message is "too" big, the connection is broken. We have tried with **7MB**, is ok, **12MB** failed. Normal message is just about **2KB**.

No error messages were found.

Our assumption are:

1. HEAP Size
2. timeout

but I really do not know how to solve them. Can somebody help me pls? Thanks!

some code here:

```
TopicConnectionFactory factory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup(Topic_Access_Params.getChild("JNDI_Name").getText());

TopicConnection conn = factory.createTopicConnection(
                    Topic_Access_Params.getChild("Security_Principal").getText(), Topic_Access_Params.getChild("Security_Credentials").getText());

TopicSession session = conn.createTopicSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup(Topic_Access_Params.getChild("Topicname").getText());

TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, Topic_Access_Params.getChild("Durable_Subscr_Name").getText());

MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(saxHandler);

subscriber.setMessageListener(handler);

conn.start();
```

Comment: 1, Could you use a simple program to reproduce this issue? 2, Could you post your environment, for example, what's the JMS server?

Comment: What JMS provider are you using?

Comment: Client stack trace ? Server error ?

Comment: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory

Comment: tibjmsnaming://ip1:7222,tibjmsnaming://ip2:7222

Comment: I did not see any client trace, do not know how to active it. after conn.start(), I can just wait until disconnection.